# greek letters ascii in vba excel

Tags: vba, ascii

i'm trying to put all the greek letters into an array except for o and v since they look like english letters. I could use the hex codes but that is cumbersome since they are done in letters. the ascii codes work much better. when i use this code

Code:

```
Dim variables2(23)
j = 0
For i = 1 To 25
    If i = 13 Or i = 15 Then
    Else
    j = j + 1
    variables2(j) = AscW((944 + i))
    End If
Next
```

The whole array gets filled with 57. but when i use this code

Code:

```
MsgBox AscW(Range("c4031").Value)
```

And place an alpha in the appropriate cell the number that comes up is 945.
My question is why does not a greek letter get populated into the array when I do variables2(j) = AscW((944 + i))?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ChrW` function, not the `AscW` function.  The `AscW` function converts a unicode character *to its unicode/utf-16 code unit*, the `ChrW` function converts a numeric unicode code unit *to its unicode string/character representation*.

```
Sub greekToMe()
Dim variables2(23)
j = 0
For i = 1 To 25
    If i = 13 Or i = 15 Then
    Else
    j = j + 1
    variables2(j) = ChrW((944 + i))
    End If
Next
'Review the conversion on a worksheet:
Range("A1:A24").Value = variables2

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, `ChrW` converts a numeric _Unicode/UTF-16 code unit_ to it's string value. ASCII is archaic.

Answer (score 1):

AscW returns the integer code for the first character of a string. Every iteration of your loop call AscW for a number starting in '9' and 57 is the code for 9.

You want to use ChrW, not AscW.